openCL with Intel GPU in Linux Mint
I am trying to get openCL to recognize my GPU, in order to use the software katago (go AI), but I'm stuck. After several tries following what I found online, clinfo is not empty anymore, it returns this:
$ clinfo
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 0

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Clover
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   No devices found in platform [Clover?]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.14
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 3.0

and here is the "Graphics" part of what returns "inxi -Fxxxrz":
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: i915 v: kernel ports:
    active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, DP-4, HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:a721 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Cheng Uei Precision Industry (Foxlink) HP 5MP Camera type: USB
    driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-1:2 chip-ID: 05c8:0613 class-ID: fe01
    serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1200 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 508x317mm (20.0x12.5")
    s-diag: 599mm (23.6")
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: LG res: 1920x1200 hz: 60 dpi: 161
    size: 302x189mm (11.9x7.4") diag: 356mm (14") modes: 1920x1200
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (RPL-U)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2 direct render: Yes

and output of lspci -k:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device a721 (rev 04)
    DeviceName: Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8b41
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

The graphic card should be Intel Iris Xe, but it does not seem to be fully recognized by the system.

As an aside, inxi -G limits the output to graphics, no need to get the full -F output.

Are you sure this is supported? I know next to nothing about this kind of thing, so are you sure it is even possible to use an integrated graphics chip for what you are trying to do?

The software is supposed to be Linux-compatible yes, aside from this I'm not sure of anything. My laptop is very recent so I hoped it would be possible.

It was solved by following the installation instructions:

Create a temporary directory
mkdir neo
cd neo


Download the packages
wget https://github.com/intel/intel-graphics-compiler/releases/download/igc-1.0.16510.2/intel-igc-core_1.0.16510.2_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/intel-graphics-compiler/releases/download/igc-1.0.16510.2/intel-igc-opencl_1.0.16510.2_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/24.13.29138.7/intel-level-zero-gpu-dbgsym_1.3.29138.7_amd64.ddeb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/24.13.29138.7/intel-level-zero-gpu_1.3.29138.7_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/24.13.29138.7/intel-opencl-icd-dbgsym_24.13.29138.7_amd64.ddeb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/24.13.29138.7/intel-opencl-icd_24.13.29138.7_amd64.deb
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/24.13.29138.7/libigdgmm12_22.3.18_amd64.deb


Verify the checksums
wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/24.13.29138.7/ww13.sum
sha256sum -c ww13.sum


Install the packages
sudo dpkg -i *.deb



